# "Generic iOS Device" missing

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, build, device

- I enrolled in the Apple Developer Program successfully in December
  2020.
- I have already registered my iPhone on the developer.apple.com website under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles --> Devices
- When I connect my iPhone to my Mac via USB, it shows up in Xcode and I can build and run my app on my device.
- As I follow along some online tutorials about creating frameworks, they talk about building the code using "Generic iOS Device" which I will need to set my deployment target to when I am ready to submit my app. I do not see "Generic iOS Device" in the list. What must I do to have "Generic iOS Device" appear in the list?

[image]

Comment: "Any iOS device". You can also build for your phone.  You just can submit a simulator build

Comment: To add, it appears your tutorial is about a year old or more. This "Any iOS Device (arm64) " has been there since Xcode 12.0 - it's meant to include the Apple Silicon devices.